# Ruby on Rails 3 Tutorial - Could not find arel-2.0.8 in any of the sources

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I've been away from my RoR 3 tutorial for about a week and I noticed that I'm getting this error in my autotest window

Could not find arel-2.0.8 in any of the sources

I can't figure out where this came from or even more importantly, how to get it resolved. I tried installing the gem for this using

gem install arel

which seemed to get the gem. Then I ran

bundle install

when I restart autotest I get the same error.

Since I am totally new to RoR these kind of problems are the most difficult to figure out when trying to follow a tutorial.

Please help.
Thanks!!
Bill

Comment: Can you add the content of `cat ~/.autotest` to your question, I wonder if one of the autotest plugins might depend on arel. Could you also check if `rake test` runs properly?

Comment: $ cat ~/.autotest
# ~.autotest
require 'autotest_notification'
SPEAKING = false
DOOM_EDITION = false
BUUF = false
PENDING = false
STICKY = false
SUCCESS_SOUND = ''
FAILURE_SOUND = ''
$

Comment: Yes! I did the cat as you suggested that didn't really give me anything to help. When I ran "rake test" it suggested: "Could not find arel-2.0.8 in any of the sources
Try running `bundle install`." This time it went out and got everything it needed and all works now. I'm confused why when I did the gem install arel then a bundle install that it didn't solve the problem. It was in a different terminal window. Wow! Thank You!

Comment: oh - and it also asked me to run "rake db:migrate". Maybe that was part of the problem. Not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Bundle installs the right version of the Gem you needed while gem install uses the newset stable version - which is not necessarily what you need in this case.

Anytime you modify your Gemfile run bundle install instead of gem install becauase Bundles takes care of Gem dependencies, installs and updates when needed.

Now if you check

```
gem list
```

you'll see more version numbers near arel. You need the 2.0.8 as the error message said.